# Trying to update the values from php to sql

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to update the values from the result but it is not able to update where is the error i am unable to find.

```
<?php

$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'user';
$db_pass = 'password';
$db_name = 'gif_wp23';

$externalQuery = new wpdb($db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $db_host);

$newQuery = $externalQuery->get_results("SELECT  `nameid` FROM  `name` WHERE  `used` =0 LIMIT 0 , 1") 
or die(mysql_error());
$query1= "UPDATE  `gif_wp23` SET  `used` =  '1' WHERE  `name`.`nameid` =   '$newQuery'";
$externalQuery->query($query1);
//print_r($newQuery);
foreach($newQuery as $q){
echo $q->nameid.'<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: what's the result of $newquery? you can tried with $query1= "UPDATE  `gif_wp23` SET  `used` =  '1' WHERE  `name`.`nameid` =".$newQuery;

Answer (score 1):

```
$query1= "UPDATE  `gif_wp23` SET  `used` =  '1' WHERE  `name`.`nameid` =   '$newQuery'";
```

THis is wrong : You are trying to update the database 'gif_wp23' `$db_name = 'gif_wp23';` and not the table name.

I think you want to update the name table and set value for its colunm "used".

```
$query1= "UPDATE  `gif_wp23`.`name` SET  `gif_wp23`.`name`.`used` =  '1' WHERE  `gif_wp23`.`name`.`nameid` =   '$newQuery'";
```

OR if you are already using gif_wp23 DB than :

```
$query1= "UPDATE  `name` SET  `name`.`used` =  '1' WHERE  `name`.`nameid` =   '$newQuery'";
```